# Protect Old Deck Posts In Soil

Tags: deck

I have a deck about 16x16' and about 4' high. It has 3 8x8" posts cemented into the ground. I am guessing they have been there since the house was built in 1990.

The posts are cemented in and currently have 1-2" of soil around them. The cement is no longer visible. I can scrape off some of the outer post pretty easily likely due to rot and moisture.

What can I do to protect them from rotting further?

Comment: After digging into the soil to the base, I realized the posts were too rotted. I am just going to replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: dig down to the abutment of the post to the concrete post slab. Pressure wash it or clean it off good. Coat it with roofers repair coating (such as EP Henry) -- in the old days they used creosote. OR, use a rubber coating like Flex Seal Liquid, Dip, or a rubber roofers product like Carlisle. Coat 6-8 inches above the terra-line where the dirt might meet the wood in the future OR up to where you are visually comfortable. It's black and not particularity pretty. Also: you can treat the wood (even if it pressure treated ground rated) with an over-the-counter wood preservative the same as commercially used in the pressure treatment process, a borate for example, such as Bora-care -- apply with a pump sprayer. This is a bug treatment essentially and a wood preservative.

Comment: Thanks. So wash, treat, coat - in that order, right?